# EclipseLink - Connection Pool Settings - Idle Connections

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I am trying to use EclipseLink JPA for a sample java application. I am trying to configure the connection pool related settings in the persistence.xml, but I could not find any suitable property for specifying the minimum Idle connections to be maintained in the connection pool. I was not able to find any details around this property or idle connection time out property in the Eclipselink documentation, [here](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.7/jpa/extensions/persistenceproperties_ref.htm#connectionpool). Can someone please point me to the documentation links that I am looking for?

Comment: As a regular java app or within a container? Within a container, you generally point the persistence unit at a container managed connection pool. EclipseLink's internal 'pool' is mostly for dev use and while I've seen shops use it in production, but most will configure an external connection pool and have EclipseLink use it instead when they get to performance tuning - you can give it a DataSource instance in the jtaDataSource/nonJtaDataSource property instead of just a string.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! This is for a regular java app. So the idea is to point to a Datasource !?, and have all idle connection settings inside the Datasource. Please correct if I have misunderstood this.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've done on projects where I need more control over pooling. EclipseLink's internal pooling is great, but runs synchronously in the app and why timeout/idle monitoring and some of the other features you'll find elsewhere are beyond what it supports.